# Code not running serially even after adding to dispatch queue

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am trying to handle a multiple call serially using queues but not working.

Basically i have a delegate function that is called by a framework. The delegate calls a function that handles database persistence. This delegate may be called more than once and i need to run the persisting function serially to avoid accessing a variable by different threads.

I use Parse as backend.

The stripped down code is as below.

```
let serialQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "serialqueue")

dispatchGroup.enter()
func delegate() {

    queue.async{

        persist(info, callback: { (success, error) in

            dispatchGroup.leave()
        })
    }

}


func persist(info: String, callback: @escaping (Bool, NSError?) -> ()) {

    PFUser.current()?.fetchInBackground(block: { (user, error) in

        print("user refreshed")

        fetchData{ (products, error) in
            if error {

                callback(false,error)
            } else {
                saveToDB()
                callback(true,nil)

            }

        }

    })

}
```

i expect that persist(), PFuser.current.fetch, fetchData,saveToDB() are executed one after other. When running, the  "user refreshed" is shown running on Main and also all the remaining code.

So i think code is not running in serial queue.

I am wondering whether PFUser.current()?.fetchInBackground call switches to Main.
if so then how to ensure persist() is called serially as added to queue?

or what else could be wrong in the way i am handling. I have tried without using DispatchGroup also.

**Question was marked duplicate and pointed to a solution but that is what i have tried and also reflects in my sample code but it is not working. Can someone with similar experience with Parse take a look?**

Thanks
Ashish

Comment: Hi David, that is what i have tried and also reflects in my sample code but it is not working. Can you please remove duplicate tag until reasonable solution is found? It seems to be impacted by Parse API call.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue and I resorted to using "aSyncAfter"

Code is:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2.0) {
     // Your Code       
}
```

You can enter the time delay after "deadline: .now() + ". You might have to add this snippet of code to all the blocks of code that you are running individually.

This delays the code that is inside it by the number of seconds you choose.

Example:

```
print("Hi")
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2.0) {
         print("Hi after 2 seconds")       
    }
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 6.0) {
         print("Hi after 6 seconds")       
    }
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 4.0) {
         print("Hi after 4 seconds")      
    }
```

Output:

```
Hi
Hi after 2 seconds
Hi after 4 seconds
Hi after 6 seconds
```

Comment: But I don’t want to run my code on main thread. Don’t want UI to be blocked.  Can asyncAfter be called on user defined queue also?

Comment: I'm not sure about that. Just try it out and let me know. I found another way to solve it too. I'll try to search for it if this doesn't work.

Comment: You can go through this tutorial too: http://www.programmingios.net/what-asynchronous-means/